# Scrapy Shell Unresponsive for Certain Urls

Tags: python, html, shell, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm working on a web crawler on the NIH grant database and I am running into an issue with scrapy's shell when I try to inspect the response object.

After entering this command:

```
scrapy shell https://projectreporter.nih.gov/project_info_results.cfm?aid=8535284&icde=27160266
```

I get this output as the shell starts up:

```
$ 2015-11-20 01:18:10 [scrapy] INFO: 

Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: tutorial)
2015-11-20 01:18:10 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-11-20 01:18:10 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tutorial.spiders'], 'LOGSTATS_INTERVAL': 0, 'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial'}
2015-11-20 01:18:10 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-11-20 01:18:10 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-11-20 01:18:10 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-11-20 01:18:10 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2015-11-20 01:18:10 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6027
2015-11-20 01:18:10 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-11-20 01:18:11 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://projectreporter.nih.gov/project_info_results.cfm?aid=8535284> (referer: None)
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x101465d10>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET https://projectreporter.nih.gov/project_info_results.cfm?aid=8535284>
[s]   response   <200 https://projectreporter.nih.gov/project_info_results.cfm?aid=8535284>
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x1028bbbd0>
[s]   spider     <DefaultSpider 'default' at 0x1047b7510>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   fetch(req_or_url) Fetch request (or URL) and update local objects
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser
2015-11-20 01:18:12 [root] DEBUG: Using default logger
2015-11-20 01:18:12 [root] DEBUG: Using default logger
```

Unfortunately it freezes there and never continues on, therefore I can't manipulate the response object or move forward.

If I put in the same command with any other url, I get this response almost immediately:

```
$ scrapy shell https://reddit.com
2015-11-20 01:20:24 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: tutorial)
2015-11-20 01:20:24 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-11-20 01:20:24 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tutorial.spiders'], 'LOGSTATS_INTERVAL': 0, 'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial'}
2015-11-20 01:20:24 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-11-20 01:20:24 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-11-20 01:20:24 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-11-20 01:20:24 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2015-11-20 01:20:24 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6028
2015-11-20 01:20:24 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-11-20 01:20:24 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.reddit.com/> from <GET https://reddit.com>
2015-11-20 01:20:25 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.reddit.com/> (referer: None)
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x107ea0d10>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET https://reddit.com>
[s]   response   <200 https://www.reddit.com/>
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x1092f7bd0>
[s]   spider     <DefaultSpider 'default' at 0x10ba31490>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   fetch(req_or_url) Fetch request (or URL) and update local objects
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser
2015-11-20 01:20:26 [root] DEBUG: Using default logger
2015-11-20 01:20:26 [root] DEBUG: Using default logger

In [1]:
```

^^^ the 'In [1]:' indicating the request and response was carried out correctly.

What's more, if I download the html of my initial url as a local file via 'Save As' and query that using the scrapy command:

```
$ scrapy shell file://127.0.0.1/path/to/file.html
```

I get the scrapy shell to work as intended.

I guess this was a long winded way of asking, what is it about the url that I am using that is tripping up the scrapy shell? is it the fact that I had to submit a search to arrive at the page? something else? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe it's a shell issue: try `scrapy shell "https://projectreporter.nih.gov/project_info_results.cfm?aid=8535284&icde=27160266"`

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. the quotes fixed it. As a follow up, do you happen to know why the quotes are only necessary on that url?

Comment: This depends on your shell, but if I'm not mistaken, `scrapy shell https://projectreporter.nih.gov/project_info_results.cfm?aid=8535284&icde=27160266` will be interpreted as `scrapy shell https://projectreporter.nih.gov/project_info_results.cfm?aid=8535284` with `&` sending this to background and then `icde=27160266` as another command. See
http://bashitout.com/2013/05/18/Ampersands-on-the-command-line.html